# Move an object from one side of the screen to the opposite Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, sprite

I have a Sprite Player which is moving by the following code

```
using UnityEngine;

public class MovePlayer : MonoBehaviour
{
public Transform player;
[SerializeField]
private float speed = 10f;

void OnMouseDrag()
{
    if (!Player.lose) { 
        Vector3 mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        mousePos.x = mousePos.x > 4.0f ? 4.0f : mousePos.x;
        mousePos.x = mousePos.x < -0.38f ? -0.38f : mousePos.x;
        player.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(player.position, 
            new Vector2(mousePos.x, player.position.y),
            speed * Time.deltaTime);
}
}
}
```

Those  two rows are for locking movement of player to both sides.

```
mousePos.x = mousePos.x > 4.0f ? 4.0f : mousePos.x;
mousePos.x = mousePos.x < -0.38f ? -0.38f : mousePos.x;
```

How can I make like if Players Sprite goes to left screen border it appearce from right side and on the contrary

Answer (score 1):

Check if this might be of help:

```
private bool mouseInScreenX { get =>
    Input.mousePosition.x < Screen.width &&
    Input.mousePosition.x > 0; 
}

private bool mouseInScreenY { get =>
    Input.mousePosition.y < Screen.height &&
    Input.mousePosition.y > 0; 
}

private void Update() {
    if (!mouseInScreenX) 
        Input.mousePosition.x = 0;
        
    if (!mouseInScreenY)
        Input.mousePosition.y = 0;
}
```

Not debuggued code, but I think its accurate enough to give you the idea.
You can use the Screen static class instead of hardcoded values to check if you are inside of the screen.
If you need to maintain the dragg, you can give to the entity beingged drag the mouse position.

Answer (score 0):

I just added this code:

```
if (player.position.x < -1)
            player.position = new Vector3(player.position.x + 10f, player.position.y, player.position.z);
        else if (player.position.x > 5)
            player.position = new Vector3(player.position.x - 10f, player.position.y, player.position.z);
```

instead of this 2 rows and it works:

```
mousePos.x = mousePos.x > 4.0f ? 4.0f : mousePos.x;
mousePos.x = mousePos.x < -0.38f ? -0.38f : mousePos.x;
```